# How to implement nested attributes of object like pandas series.str.find()

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas has a neat feature where methods are given a namespace almost, like

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series("Hi there Stack Overflow!".split())

print(s.str.len())

# 0    2
# 1    5
# 2    5
# 3    9
# dtype: int64
```

Here you see that the `str` methods like `len` are collected under a `str` namespace.

I have an object that implements a lot of methods. I'd like to group them with attribute accesses like shown above. What is the simplest way to do that?

If you could use the template below to make a dummy example that just prints `attribute` with a call to `Series.str.print_attribute()` that would likely be the simplest way to show how it works.

```
class Series():
    attribute = 42
    str = ???

    def __init__(self):
        ???

    ???
```

Comment: Why not just name your functions like `Series.str_print_attribute()`? Creating a useless object that can be accessed as `Series.str` just because you want to group some methods doesn't sound like a great idea.

Comment: You might be right. But then an addendum to my question is `why does pandas do this?` And still I'd be interested to know if there is a simple way to do this :)

Comment: Probably because the library is absolutely massive so it's useful to have this kind of structure. It differentiates string methods from datetime methods, for example.

Comment: Just define a new class and assign an instance of that class to `str`. Pandas does this too: `>>> s.str
<pandas.core.strings.StringMethods object at 0x7f1014a14610>
`

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta But how does the str object know about the series object?

Comment: `self.str = StringMethods(self)` you create a loop in the references, `Series` has a reference to `StringsMethods` and `StringMethods` has a reference to `Series`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas defines a `StringMethods` class that defines those methods. It then simply passes the `Series` object to the constructor creating a reference loop:

```
class StringMethods:
    def __init__(self, series):
        self.series = series
    def len(self):
        # compute length on self.series
        return result


class Series:
    def __init__(values):
        # init internal data
        self.str = StringMethods(self)
```

Depending on the implementation you could simply forward a reference to `_internal_data` to `StringMethods` instead of the whole `Series` object, avoiding the reference loop.